# VBA and Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is my first time posting a question.  I am new to this and am using Access 2016. I have created several reports to use as letters and I am working on IIf statements in order to minimize the number of reports I have to create.  So basically I can not find the error or maybe the correct way to write the following statement pasted below and I've only posted the portion that I am having difficulty with.

```
="We, " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_Last] & " & " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_Last] & ", as owners of " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskAddress] & ", " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskCounty] &",  having already agreed to pay Murphy Loss Assessors” & IIf([Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_Discounted]>0,”a discounted fee upon settlement of our home insurance claim now confirm that we will discharge this payment of €"&[Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_Discounted], “10% plus VAT upon settlement of our home insurance claim now confirm that we will discharge this payment of €"& [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_LA]) & " upon receipt of settlement cheque now expected in the amount of €" & Format([Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![DueNow],"Standard") & "."
```

Comment: Your code as displayed is not readable. Show the entire module, and to make it readable, skip 2 lines after the initial paragraph and then indent your code. It will then show up in a way we can read. Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you read it now?  Also, the error is "The expression you entered contains invalid syntax, or you need to enclose you text data in quotes"

Comment: You're only showing a part of the whole line. The error you're getting could be from a missing quote, or possibly a missing paren, or any number of other things. Without the whole line, I can't tell where the error is occurring.

Comment: Is that an entry within a cell? Does it have an "=" at the beginning? e.g. =", having agreed...

Comment: I cannot seem to post the entire code so in pieces...

Comment: ="We, " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_Last] & " & " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_Last] & ", as owners of " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskAddress] & ", " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskCounty] &

Comment: It is with a text box

Answer (score 0):

You have some typographic quotes in there `” “` - if these are also in your code, you must replace them with standard quotes `" "`.

Hint: use a **text editor** to edit SQL (or Stack Overflow questions), not Word.

And:

`this payment of €"&[Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]!`

Always put a space before and after `&` :

`this payment of €" & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]!`

Comment: Thank you.  I made corrections and I am no longer receiving an error message but it is not doing what I want it to

Comment: @Elizabeth: Please **edit** your question, add what it does and what it should do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some Null values, which Nz will correct here:

```
="We, " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client_Last] & " & " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_First] & " " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![Client2_Last] & ", as owners of " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskAddress] & ", " & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmRisk]![RiskCounty] & ", having already agreed to pay Murphy Loss Assessors " & IIf(Nz([Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_Discounted],0)>0,"a discounted fee upon settlement of our home insurance claim now confirm that we will discharge this payment of €" &[Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_Discounted], "10% plus VAT upon settlement of our home insurance claim now confirm that we will discharge this payment of €" & [Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![Fees_LA]) & " upon receipt of settlement cheque now expected in the amount of €" & Format([Forms]![frmClaimDataEntry]![subfrmSettlement]![DueNow],"Standard") & "."
```

Also, you may have misspelled a control name.